# Get rid of the '' on a list

Tags: python

Bee
n trying to do this all the morning but can't seem to figure it out.

```
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('image_name.png',blocklist="'",detail=0)
```

the output given is always some numbers with the apostrophes. Ex: '300526'. I want to take them out and store the numbers on a single string.
Im not able to do str.replace tho because the output given by result() seems to be a list

Answer (score 3):

You could just replace the apostrophes by:

```
result.replace("'", "")
```

Alternatively you could use regex to remove anything but digits, like:

```
re.sub(r"\D", "", result)
```

Comment: I can't do any replace because the output it's a list and seems to be taking temporary those digits, so anything to replace gives me an error

Comment: can u show us the output?

Comment: [([[26, 8], [222, 8], [222, 58], [26, 58]], '540270', 0.6069280095269785)] That would be the "real" output but i don't understand why it still storage as a list when the only digits that came off with the parameter to show those ones (540270)

Comment: Thats not a list! Thats a list, in a list, in a touple, in a list!

Comment: Try to print result[0][1]

Comment: That was it! I tried that without all the listing mode and wasn't any way to make to work, but just did with the list active and YEA! It worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `replace` function which is a builtin from Python. Based on your example you can use it like this:

```
result = '300526'
result.replace("'", "")

print(result)
```

Output:

```
300526
```